# If else statement not giving expected result

Tags: javascript

data1 variable contanins "NotExist" string but executing else statement.

```
if(data1=="NotExist")
{   document.getElementById("errcorrectwfrm").style.display="inline";   
 return false;                          
}
else{ alert("Thanks for choosing albc,now you can go ahead");
 $.modal.close();                           
}
```

Comment: `data1 variable contanins "NotExist"`? what is the actual value of `data1` - since you are checking for equality it has to be exact `NotExist`, like `data='NotExist'` not something like `data1='soemvalue NotExist'`

Comment: Can you add _complete_ and _relevant_ code

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: Use debugger to check data1 value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that data1 value is not the same as your are expecting it so the code is executing the else statement.
Kindly console.log(data1) or alert(data1) you will come to know the exact value in it.

I am assuming there might be a white space somewhere in your data1 value which is causing the problem.
Kindly check the length of the string and you will come to know.

Hope this helps